# Ошибка "Main method not found"

Tags: java

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Error: Main method not found in class Vehicle, please define the main method as:
>    public static void main(String[] args)
> or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
> ```

Код:

```
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;
    int mpg;
    int fuelcap;

    void range(){
        System.out.println(mpg*fuelcap);
    }
}

class AddMath {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle();

        minivan.passengers = 9;
        minivan.mpg = 12;
        minivan.fuelcap = 14;

        sportscar.fuelcap = 20;
        sportscar.mpg = 24;
        sportscar.passengers = 2;

        minivan.range();

        sportscar.range();
    }
}
```

Comment: Переименуйте файл в AddMath.java или переместите метод main в класс Vehicle

Answer (score 1):

Метод `main` должен находиться в классе с именем совпадающим с именем файла. У вас `main` находится в классе `AddMath`, а файл (судя по ошибке) называется `Vehicle.java`.

Переименуйте файл в AddMath.java или переместите метод `main` в класс `Vehicle`.